# JSF: Set the validation message to english in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2.2

I am lerning JSF framwork and I want to Change the language of the shown validation message to english in Eclipse instead f of my own language. How can I  get it to work in Eclipse?

[image]

Comment: @BalusC: I mean the red sentence after `UserName`?

Comment: In Chrome  I have English on the top: Setting-->Show advanced Settings -->languages and Input Settings -->here (English is on the top)